# Writing in .txt file wont save

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a game in pygame and want to save the high score. Every time I exit and re-run my code, the score never saves into my file. I have looked into possible problems and have tried closing manually and not. If anybody knows what I might have done from the code below it would be much appreciated.(keep in mind I have defined the score elsewhere in the code)

```
#This opens the file and sets the score as self.highscore
HS_FILE = "highscore.txt"
self.dir = path.dirname(__file__)
with open(path.join(self.dir, HS_FILE), 'w') as f:
    try:
       self.highscore = int(f.read())
    except:
       self.highscore = 0
#This is elsewhere in the code but the code around it runs fine
#self.score is created elsewhere
if self.score > self.highscore:
    self.highscore = self.score
    with open(path.join(self.dir, HS_FILE), 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(self.score))
#for the purpose of confusion I will just print out the score to the command line
print(str(self.highscore))
```

Comment: to read you have to use `"r"`(like "read") but you use `"w"` which clears file.

Comment: BTW: you don't have to use `str()` in `print(str(self.highscore))` and `f.write(str(self.score))` - it will convert to string automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open(path.join(self.dir, HS_FILE), 'w') as f:
```

You're opening the file in write mode ('w') and then trying to read from it which won't work.  Because you've used an except clause that catches everything, you're not seeing the error that would look like this:

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Additionally, because you're using a with statement, the file is opened in write mode and then closed again, which as a commenter has already pointed out will actually result in the file being emptied.  Use read mode ('r') to open the file and see if that fixes things.